# Problem with Sequences..

Tags: sequences-and-series

I'm having trouble with a homework question, and cant see where im going wrong. 
The question is as follows:

Let $x\gt1$ and let $a_n = 1+\frac 1x+\frac 1{x^2} + \cdots + \frac 1{x^n}$ for all $n\ge1$.

(i) Prove that $a_{n+1} \gt a_n$ for all $n\ge1$.

(ii) Prove that $a_n\lt \frac x{x-1}$ for all $n\ge1$.

(iii) Prove that ($a_n$) is convergent.

Part (ii) and (iii) are fine. Just part (i)

Comment: $$a_{n+1} - a_n = \frac{1}{x^{n+1}} > 0$$

Comment: I have found that the block from $$\frac 1{x^2}$$ to $$\frac 1{x^n}$$  plus the 1 cancel in both sides. 
This leaves with $$\frac 1{x^{n+1}} \gt \frac 1x$$

Comment: $a_{n+1}$ is $a_{n}$ plus something positive:  $a_n=\sum_{i=0}^n\frac{1}{x^i}$, so $a_{n+1}=\sum_{i=0}^{n+1}\frac{1}{x^i}$.

Comment: $\frac{1}{x}$ cancels too. Why do you start with $\frac{1}{x^2}$?

Comment: in $a_{n+1}$ how is there a $\frac 1x$ term? I think this is where im getting confused...

Comment: Never mind. I just copped what i was missing. I'm a fool.

Comment: $a_{n+1}=1+\frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{x^2}+\cdots +\frac{1}{x^{n+1}}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a) $a_{n+1}=a_n+\frac{1}{x^{n+1}}$ and the last one is greater than $a_n$, being
$\frac{1}{x^{n+1}}>0$.

Comment: in $a_{n+1}$ is the $n=1$ term not $$\frac 1{x^2}$$ Thus leaving a $\frac 1x$ in $a_n$ that doesn't cancel?

Comment: Sorry but I don't understand your problem. Can you be clearer, please?

Comment: I thought the whole sequence changes, but copped that its only an extra term added to the end. It's just very early and I must not be fully awake it seems.. Thanks for the answer though! It helped me cop on

Comment: I'm glad you understood!